# Reading a downloaded file from ftp server is not shoing data after using fgetcsv function

Tags: php, curl, ftp

I am using a cURL request for downloading a CSV file from an FTP server.

I have downloaded my file in my webroot folder (in my given path).

But when I am trying to read the CSV data from the file it isn't showing anything.
`$leadDir` is path of my downloaded file.

```
if ($fp = fopen($leadDir, "r")) {
    echo $fp;
    echo "come after fopen";
    while ($CSVData = fgetcsv($fp)) {
        echo "</br>";
        echo "come after fgetcsv";
    }
}
```

It is not going inside the `while` loop.

I have also checked the file permissions, I have given it 777 permissions.

Where is it going wrong?

Comment: @ShaquinTrifonoff I don't think this is the issue..

Comment: No, of course not :-) It's just making the HTML valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the code should be ok, so my best answer is that the path is incorrect, try something like

```
$cwd = getcwd();
$leadDir = $cwd.'/relativePathToFile';

if(file_exists($leadDir)){
    if (($fp = fopen($leadDir, "r"))) {
        echo $fp;
        echo "come after fopen";
        while ($CSVData = fgetcsv($fp)) {
            echo "</br>";echo "come after fgetcsv";
        } 
    }
 }
```

Comment: I have tried that.. File is exists and it is coming inside the if but not coming inside while..

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks like it should work. Here is the code I would use:

```
<?php
if($handle = fopen('test.csv', 'r')) {
    $data = fgetcsv($handle);
    if($data) {
        echo '<pre>';
        var_dump($data);
        echo '</pre>';
    }
}
?>
```

Try executing this code:

```
var_dump(file_exists($leadDir));
```

If the file exists, it will output

```
bool(true)
```

otherwise it will output

```
bool(false)
```

Also, is `$leadDir` a *directory* or a *file*?

Comment: @Learner What does `var_dump(file_exists($leadDir));` output?

Comment: What about `echo '<pre>' . file_get_contents($leadDir) . '</pre>';`?

Answer (score 1):

fgetcsv() returns NULL if an invalid handle is supplied or FALSE on other errors, including end of file.

Try with:

```
if (($fp = fopen($leadDir, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    echo $fp;
    echo "come after fopen";
    while (($CSVData = fgetcsv($fp,1000,',')) !== FALSE) {
        echo "</br>";
        echo "come after fgetcsv";
    }
}
```

If it still does not enter in the while loop, try to check the end of file of the CSV.

Note: If PHP is not properly recognizing the line endings when reading files either on or created by a Macintosh computer, enabling the auto_detect_line_endings run-time configuration option may help resolve the problem. (source [PHP.net](http://it.php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php))

Answer (score 0):

Check the owner of your destination directory. Try to give the permission to `www-data` user.

You can do this programmatically by using `chown` [function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chown.php) for downloaded files.

Here is the syntax.

```
bool chown ( string $filename , mixed $user )
```